# Graph API List appRoleAssignments granted to a user returns no value

Tags: azure, api, rest, graph

This API request worked a couple days ago but now it returns no value even though it's 200 OK.

Even the documentation using the "try it" doesn't work and returns no value.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Tried the API request to our own tenant and no value returns.

The documentation also provides examples but that doesn't work either.

Also tried the Beta API.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I am facing a similar issue and wondered if your solution might help me.

Answer (score 0):

To List **`appRoleAssignments`** granted to a user, I used the below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/appRoleAssignments
```

[image]

When I tried with the user with no role assignments assigned, I got the **200 OK response but no data**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/appRoleAssignments
```

[image]

> **Note** that: The issue usually occurs if the user doesn't have any role assigned.

**To resolve the issue, check the below:**

- If the query worked a couple days ago but now it returns no value, the check whether the user have roles assigned in the Azure Portal.
- Try with another user and check if the query returns null values.
- ***If still the issue persists,*** check if the user has proper permissions to execute the query like `User.ReadBasic.All`/`Directory.Read.All`.